# socket.emit is not working in session.socket.io

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, rabbitmq, session.socket.io

I am trying to create simple chat application using session.socket.io and rabbitMQ and redis for session storage.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
        http = require('http'),
        path = require('path'),
        redis = require('redis'),
        amqp = require('amqp'),
        logger = require('morgan');
    users = {};


    var session = require('express-session');
    var rabbitConn = amqp.createConnection({});
    var chatExchange;
    rabbitConn.on('ready', function () {
        chatExchange = rabbitConn.exchange('chatExchange', { 'type': 'fanout' });
    });

    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);

    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.set("transports", ["polling"]);



    var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
        rClient = redis.createClient(),
        sessionStore = new RedisStore({ client: rClient });


    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');


    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(methodOverride());


    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(session({ store: sessionStore, key: 'jsessionid', secret: 'your secret here', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));


    var SessionSockets = require('session.socket.io');
    var sessionSockets = new SessionSockets(io, sessionStore, cookieParser, 'jsessionid');

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {
        console.log('sessionSockets connected');
        socket.on('send message', function (data) {
            io.sockets.emit('new message', { message: data, user: socket.nickName });
        }).on('new user', function (data, callBack) {
            console.log('new user called');
            if (data in users) {
                callBack(false);
            } else {
                socket.nickName = data;
                users[socket.nickName] = socket;
                updateUserName();
                callBack(true);
            }

        }).on('disconnect', function () {
            if (!socket.nickName) return;

            delete users[socket.nickName];
            updateUserName();
        }).on('connectiontest', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        function updateUserName() {
            var test = {}
            io.sockets.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users));
        }
    });

    server.listen(3003);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    </head
    <body>
        <div id="nickWrap">
            <p>Enter userName</p>
            <p id="nickError"></p>

            <form id="setNick">
                <input size="35" id="nickName" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="contentWrap">
            <div id="chatWrap">
                <div id="chat"></div>
                <form id="send-message">
                    <input size="35" id="message" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="users"></div>


        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                  var host = window.location.host;
            console.log('host',host);
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + host, {reconnect:false, 'try multiple transports':false});
            var intervalID;
            var reconnectCount = 0;

            socket.on('connect', function () {
                 socket.emit('connectiontest', 'Hello server');
                console.log('connected');
            });
            socket.on('connecting', function () {
                console.log('connecting');
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                console.log('disconnect');
                intervalID = setInterval(tryReconnect, 4000);
            });
            socket.on('connect_failed', function () {
                console.log('connect_failed');
            });
            socket.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
            socket.on('reconnect_failed', function () {
                console.log('reconnect_failed');
            });
            socket.on('reconnect', function () {
                console.log('reconnected ');
            });
            socket.on('reconnecting', function () {
                console.log('reconnecting');
            });

            var tryReconnect = function () {
                ++reconnectCount;
                if (reconnectCount == 5) {
                    clearInterval(intervalID);
                }
                console.log('Making a dummy http call to set jsessionid (before we do socket.io reconnect)');
                $.ajax('/')
                    .success(function () {
                        console.log("http request succeeded");
                        //reconnect the socket AFTER we got jsessionid set
                        socket.socket.reconnect();
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                    }).error(function (err) {
                        console.log("http request failed (probably server not up yet)");
                    });
            };


                    var messageForm=$("#send-message");
                    var message=$("#message");
                    var chat=$("#chat");

                    var nickForm=$("#setNick");
                    var nickBox=$("#nickName");
                    var nickError=$("#nickError");

                    nickForm.submit(function(e){

                        e.preventDefault(e);
                        socket.emit('new user',nickBox.val(),function(data){
                             alert('hi');
                            if(data){
                                $("#nickWrap").hide();
                                $("#contentWrap").show();
                            }else{
                                nickError.html('User Name already taken');
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    messageForm.submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        socket.emit('send message',message.val());
                        message.val('');
                    });

                    socket.on('new message',function(data){
                        chat.append(data.message+':->'+data.user+'</br>');
                    }).on('usernames',function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                        var html="";
                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            html+=data[i]+'</br>';
                        }
                        $("#users").html(html);
                    });

                });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please add details.

Comment: i'm not getting any error

Comment: its not hitting  server code